# Division in the ring of formal power series

Tags: ring-theory, formal-power-series

I was wondering if the following simplification is allowed in the ring of formal power series:

If I have $ \displaystyle\frac{1+x}{1+2x+x^2}$ , can I simplify it so that it is equal to $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+x}$.

I think that it can't be simplified, but i would appreciate if someone clarifies my doubt.

Thanks

Comment: Technically the ring of formal power series does not contain $1/(1+x)$; this is understood to mean the power series $1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$. So yes, both expressions are the same here.

Comment: thanks @ElliotG. Since I gave a specific case, I would like to know if this rule follows in general. For example, if I were to treat formal power series as one does in calculus and I have an expression in which the numerator is just a factor of the denominator, can I cancel the corresponding factors?

Comment: Yes.  When you say that the formal power series represents some rational function, you mean that it's the Taylor series of that function in some disk.  It's also the Taylor series of the function you get by canceling common factors.

Comment: Thank you @saulspatz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *[formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series)* $\frac{1+x}{1+2x+x^2}$ *can* be simplified. We consider the ring $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ of formal power series, where we take as ring the field $\mathbb{C}$. The formal power series
\begin{align*}
A(x)=1+x\in\mathbb{C}[[x]]
\end{align*}
has a constant term $1\ne 0$ which guarantees the existence of a multiplicative inverse $A^{-1}(x)$ with
\begin{align*}
A(x)A^{-1}(x)=1
\end{align*}
The multiplicative inverse $A^{-1}(x)=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n$ and we can easily show
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{A(x)A^{-1}(x)}&=(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^{n}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=1}
\end{align*}

Two more aspects:

- We recall the multiplicative inverse of formal power series is *unique* provided it exists.
- We commonly write the inverse multiplicative of a formal power series $C(x)$ as
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{C(x)}:=C^{-1}(x)
  \end{align*}
  which enables us to write
  \begin{align*}
  A^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots
  \end{align*}

> We can now show *purely algebraically* that OPs two formal power series are equal. We thereby apply well-known algebraic rules which are also valid in the ring of formal power series. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1+x}{1+2x+x^2}}&=(1+x)\left(1+2x+x^2\right)^{-1}\\
> &=(1+x)\left((1+x)(1+x)\right)^{-1}\\
> &=(1+x)\left((1+x)^{-1}(1+x)^{-1}\right)\\
> &=\left((1+x)(1+x)^{-1}\right)(1+x)^{-1}\\
> &=1\cdot (1+x)^{-1}\\
> &=(1+x)^{-1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1+x}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

Note we do *not* use any *[Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)* which considers a power series as *analytic* object where coefficients are defined via (analytic) derivatives. We do also *not* consider any radius of convergence since $x\in\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ is just a *formal* placeholder for a sequence $(0,\color{blue}{1},0,0,\ldots)$ and is not subject of evaluation at certain points of $\mathbb{C}$.